# Vectorized way of dropping duplicates from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I denote duplicate values in a file with "duplicates" using the following (working) code:

```
frame=pd.read_excel(io=r"D:XXXX\test.xlsx")
df=pd.DataFrame(frame)


dup=[df.duplicated(subset=(i),keep=False) for i in [("id","Type"),("id","Time"),("Time","Type")]]
duplicate="duplicate"

for i in range(len(dup)):
    for j in range(len(dup[i])):
        if dup[i][j]==True:
            df.loc[j,"Attribute"]=duplicate
```

The shape of the DataFrame is something like:

```
id  Type    Time
12  ab  12:00:00
11  cd  11:12:22
663 dfd 10:00:00
```

But if there are many rows in a file this approch gets tedious. 
I'm searching for a way to replace the loop by a combination of lambda or apply with LC

Thanks for any response

Comment: Can you post sample data? This is likely not the most efficient approach.

Comment: i'm sorry, after seeing your approach i got a bit confused, you only want to drop duplicates in your dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe his is what you're looking for using [pandas.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
for i in [("id","Type"),("id","Time"),("Time","Type")]:
    df['Attribute'] = df.duplicated(subset=i,keep=False).apply(lambda x: "duplicate" if x else "not duplicate")
```

solution with [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
for i in [("id","Type"),("id","Time"),("Time","Type")]:
    df['Attribute'] = np.where(df.duplicated(subset=i,keep=False),"duplicate","not duplicate")
```

i used this dataframe as input:

```
    id   Type      Time
0   12     ab  12:00:00
1   12  abacd  11:12:22
2  663    dfd  10:00:00
3   11     ab  12:00:00
4  663    dfd  10:00:00
5   11   caad  11:12:22
```

this is the output:

```
    id   Type      Time      Attribute
0   12     ab  12:00:00      duplicate
1   12  abacd  11:12:22  not duplicate
2  663    dfd  10:00:00      duplicate
3   11     ab  12:00:00      duplicate
4  663    dfd  10:00:00      duplicate
5   11   caad  11:12:22  not duplicate
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have edited my question - I don't want to drop the duplicates but mark them. This code is working for me but I am searching for a more vectorized way

Comment: Nearly what I am looking for. As you can see the code contains the variable dup. Here all three "column combiations" are covered. How can I incorporate this step in your code?

Comment: @2Obe edited with something that suits your needs, i'll be still optimizing and looking for a numpy solution as well so stay tuned